# Block and Inline display in percentage layout

Tags: css, layout

I'm building a layout with a header navigational, main content, and footer sections. Within each section are numerous divs. I'm trying to get the div content to stay within each element and have each element stack on top of each other. Do I need to use display:block to stack these elements? I've tried display: inline-block and they don't stack properly.

Comment: Posted an answer, but if that doesn't help you, can you provide more detail?

Comment: Yes display: block will produce the desired result. What exactly is your concern?

Comment: Salman A, I just wanted to confirm I was thinking about it the right way because I was playing with different display attributes for the layout and not always getting the right effect. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block-level elements span the width of their container and clear on both sides, so yes, you will need to use `display: block;` (or use block-level containers like `div`, `p`, etc. to achieve this stacking.